# How to connect multiple markers using google map in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have to connect multiple markers points to show direction in google map. I have used codeigniter. I have referred this [link](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library)

There is no such example of connecting routes between markers. Kindly help me out.

Controller:

```
public function geoLocation(){

        $this->load->library('googlemaps');

        $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
        $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
        $config['directions'] = TRUE;
        $config['directionsStart'] = 'Hadapsar, Pune, India';
        //$config['directionsDivID'] = 'swargate, Pune, India';
        $config['directionsEnd'] = 'Bavdhan, Pune, India';

        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);


        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

        $this->load->view('google-map', $data);

}
```

my updated controller method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');

        $config['center'] = 'Pune, India';
        $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
        $config['directionsMode']="WALKING";
        $config['directionsWaypointArray'] = array('Hadapsar, Pune, India','Swargate, Pune, India','Bavdhan, Pune, India');

        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = 'Hadapsar, Pune, India';
        //$marker['onmouseover'] = 'ahssdfsdf';
        $marker['infowindow_open']= true;

        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);



        $marker['position'] = 'Bavdhan, Pune, India';

        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<?php echo $map['js']; ?>
    <div id="nevi">
                <div id="menu">
                  <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
                    <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
                      <li class="TabbedPanelsTab"  tabindex="0" style="font-size:14px" id="today_st">Today's status </li>
                      <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" id="report" tabindex="0"  style="font-size:14px">Reports</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup" style="margin-top:74px;">

                      <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
                      <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is not the way to ask questions on this site. Show us your code and what you have tried. Further to that it is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to use the Directions to show a route, or do you want to link muliple markers by a line (Polyline). In any case, the documentation on the link in your question contains **everything you need**. I was able to find it in less than a minute.

Comment: I have attached my code. I want to show route direction the with marker points on 3 locations. "Hadapsar" is my starting point, "swargate" is my middle point, "Bavdhan" is my end point. Using these three i have to show directions between them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify this:

```
directionsWaypointArray
```

According to [the code](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Googlemaps.php):

```
var $directionsWaypointArray = array(); // An array of waypoints. eg array("Boston, MA", "Times Square, NY");
```

Waypoints are the bits between your start and end points, so I assume you'd just need to do:

```
$config['directionsStart'] = 'Hadapsar, Pune, India';
$config['directionsEnd'] = 'Bavdhan, Pune, India';
$config['directionsWaypointArray'] = array("swargate, Pune, India");
```

Comment: PS: the documentation **doesn't** give any examples of using the directionsWaypointArray

Comment: I have tried this. But unfortunately it is not working. Kindly update other approach on this.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you're adding the waypoints array, and also the generated Javascript?

Comment: I have updated a code. Can you take a look into that.

Comment: Ah, you still need to specify directionsStart and directionsEnd.  I'll update my code to give an example of what I think would work

Comment: Ok fine. Update your conttroller method and html code also.

Comment: Add the generated javascript to your question

Comment: I haven't used javascript here.

Comment: @user3865038 on your web page the Codeigniter Google Maps library writes out javascript, based on how you configure it in your PHP.  I want to see what that JS looks like

Comment: I'm not asking for your HTML, I'm asking for the Javascript that the CodeIgniter Maps library is adding to your page.  View source, find the javascript

Comment: I haven't added the any javascript library coz codeigniter gives a library called "Googlemaps" I am using that one.

Comment: Right. I want to know exactly what Javascript that Codeigniter 'Googlemaps' library is writing out to your web page.  View Source.  Find the bit that has the javascript in it, copy it and add it to your question or upload it to JSFiddle or something like that.